# how to convert array 1 dimensional to be 2 dimensional in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have one array as :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 11
    [1] => 4
)
```

I want convert it to be array like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => array
           (
              [0] => 11
           )
    [1] => array 
          (
              [0] => 4
          )
)
```

Thanks you very much for your answer

Comment: Have you written any code that you can show us?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your array is in the variable `$array`, you could simply use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$array = array_map( function( $val ) {
    return array( $val );
}, $array );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast each element as an array like this:

Code:

```
$array=[11,4];
$array=array_map(function($v){return (array)$v;},$array);
var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 11,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 4,
  ),
)
```

---

Or write a foreach loop and make the elements modifiable by reference:

```
foreach($array as &$v){
    $v=(array)$v;
}
```